# Python, Convert bson output of mongodump to array of json objects (dictionaries)

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo, bson

I have dumped a mongodb collection using the `mongodump` command. The output is a dump directory which has these files:

```
dump/
    |___coll.bson
    |___coll.metadata.json
```

How can I open the exported files to a array of dictionaries that work in python?
I tried the following and none worked:

```
with open('dump/coll.bson', 'rb') as f:
    coll_raw = f.read()
import json
coll = json.loads(coll_raw)

# Using pymongo
from bson.json_util import loads
coll = loads(coll_raw)

ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should try:

```
from bson import BSON
with open('dump/coll.bson', 'rb') as f:
    coll_raw = f.read()

coll = bson.decode_all(coll_raw)
```

Comment: This probably means that your BSON is incorrect, can you send me a sample BSON object that you are trying to decode ?

Comment: The bson file is the dump I got with `mongodump`. The file is huge. Let me see if I can replicate the error with a small database.

Comment: Did you try running `BSON.is_valid(coll_row)`?

Comment: @YashMehrotra here's the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6yyssja0la0ctln/dump.zip?dl=0
Direct output of mongodump

Comment: @Quirk `object 'BSON' has no attribute 'is_valid'`

Comment: @CentAu My Bad. Try `bson.is_valid(coll_raw)`. Ref: https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/

Comment: @Quirk It returns false. But the file is the output of mongodb. It this doesn't return a valid bson, how can I get a json/bson dump from mongo that will work in python?

Comment: @CentAu Looks like when you took the dump it got corrupted. Have you tried any other collection or redumping?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98163/discussion-between-quirk-and-centau).

Comment: Hi @CentAu , I decoded your bson. Please check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was answered a long time ago, but you could try decoding each document separately and then you'd know which doc is causing the problem.

I use this library:  https://github.com/bauman/python-bson-streaming

```
from bsonstream import KeyValueBSONInput
f = open("restaurants.bson", 'rb')
stream = KeyValueBSONInput(fh=f)
for dict_data in stream:
    print dict_data
f.close()
```

I see 25359 records which all seem to decode to something like:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('5671bb2e111bb7b9a7ce4d9a'),
 u'address': {u'building': u'351',
              u'coord': [-73.98513559999999, 40.7676919],
              u'street': u'West   57 Street',
              u'zipcode': u'10019'},
 u'borough': u'Manhattan',
 u'cuisine': u'Irish',
 u'grades': [{u'date': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 6, 0, 0),
              u'grade': u'A',
              u'score': 2},
             {u'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 22, 0, 0),
              u'grade': u'A',
              u'score': 11},
             {u'date': datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 31, 0, 0),
              u'grade': u'A',
              u'score': 12},
             {u'date': datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 29, 0, 0),
              u'grade': u'A',
              u'score': 12}],
 u'name': u'Dj Reynolds Pub And Restaurant',
 u'restaurant_id': u'30191841'}
```